# Upward side arrow in a simple tikz fluxogram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have been trying to implement a upward arrow as in the picture bellow but I am having a lot of trouble to implement it on Tikz. My main issue, is the upward arrow that closes the loop, I haven't been able to make it going upward by the side to reach the implementation block on the right side.

[image]

The code that I have been testing is this:

```
\tikzset{
    block/.style = {draw, rectangle,
        minimum height=2cm,
        minimum width=3cm},
    input/.style = {coordinate,node distance=1cm},
    output/.style = {coordinate,node distance=1cm},
    arrow/.style={draw, -latex,node distance=3cm},
    pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={latex-, black,node distance=2cm}},
    sum/.style = {draw, circle, node distance=1cm},
}



\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1.5cm,>=latex']
    \node [block, name=input] {Implementation};
    \node [block, below=of input] (controller) {Optimization};
    \draw [->] (input) -- node {Data} (controller);
    \draw [->] (controller) |- node {Control Inputs} (input);
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{center}
\caption{TikzPicture}\label{fig}
\end{figure}
```

Any suggestions how to implement this outward arrow by the side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close to to desred arrows position: Instead of `\draw [->] (controller) |- node {Control Inputs} (input);` you should write `\draw [->] (controller.east) -- ++ (1,0)  |- node {Control Inputs} (input);`

Complete MWE (with changed nodes name and with only relevant style definitions):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right,
node distance = 12mm and 8mm,
 block/.style = {draw=blue, very thick, rounded corners, 
                 minimum height=2cm, minimum width=3cm,
                 top color=blue!10, bottom color=blue!50},
   arr/.style = {-Stealth, thick, rounded corners}
                        ]
\node (in)      [block]                 {Implementation};
\node (cntrl)   [block, below=of in]    {Optimization};
\draw [arr] (in)    edge ["Data"] (cntrl) 
            (cntrl.east) -- ++(1,0) |- (in)     % <---
            node[pos=0.25, align=left] {Control\\ Inputs} (in);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]